# FFMPEG:avfilter_graph_create_filter method failed when initializing filter

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, video-processing, transcoding

I want to implement the [transcoding.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcoding_8c-example.html) sample hosted on the FFMPEG website. But the `avfilter_graph_create_filter`function failed with a return code of `-22` (Line 175). I only made a minor change to the source code to make it runnable in my C++ console application. I also searched it online, but couldn't find any helpful information.
Below is my code:

```
 extern "C" 
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>
}
static AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx;
static AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;
typedef struct FilteringContext {
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
} FilteringContext;
static FilteringContext *filter_ctx;

static int init_filter(FilteringContext* fctx, AVCodecContext *dec_ctx,
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, const char *filter_spec)
{
    char args[512];
    int ret = 0;
    AVFilter *buffersrc = NULL;
    AVFilter *buffersink = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *inputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }
    if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }
        /*sprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
            dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
            dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);*/
        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
            args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }
        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
            NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }
        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->pix_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->pix_fmt),
            AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output pixel format\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }
    else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }
        if (!dec_ctx->channel_layout)
            dec_ctx->channel_layout =
            av_get_default_channel_layout(dec_ctx->channels);
        /*snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "time_base=%d/%d:sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=0x%"PRIx64,
            dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den, dec_ctx->sample_rate,
            av_get_sample_fmt_name(dec_ctx->sample_fmt),
            dec_ctx->channel_layout);*/
        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
            args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }
        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
            NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }
        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_fmts",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->sample_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_fmt),
            AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample format\n");
            goto end;
        }
        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "channel_layouts",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->channel_layout,
            sizeof(enc_ctx->channel_layout), AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output channel layout\n");
            goto end;
        }
        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_rates",
            (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->sample_rate, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_rate),
            AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample rate\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }
    else {
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }
    /* Endpoints for the filter graph. */
    outputs->name = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx = 0;
    outputs->next = NULL;
    inputs->name = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx = 0;
    inputs->next = NULL;
    if (!outputs->name || !inputs->name) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }
    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_spec,
        &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;
    /* Fill FilteringContext */
    fctx->buffersrc_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    fctx->buffersink_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    fctx->filter_graph = filter_graph;
end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
    avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);
    return ret;
}
static int init_filters(void)
{
    const char *filter_spec;
    unsigned int i;
    int ret;
    filter_ctx = (FilteringContext *)av_malloc_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*filter_ctx));
    if (!filter_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        filter_ctx[i].buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].buffersink_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].filter_graph = NULL;
        if (!(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
            || ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO))
            continue;
        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            filter_spec = "null"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for video */
        else
            filter_spec = "anull"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for audio */
        ret = init_filter(&filter_ctx[i], ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec,
            ofmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec, filter_spec);
        if (ret)
            return ret;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    AVPacket packet = {  NULL, 0 };
    AVFrame *frame = NULL;
    enum AVMediaType type;
    unsigned int stream_index;
    unsigned int i;
    int got_frame;
    int(*dec_func)(AVCodecContext *, AVFrame *, int *, const AVPacket *);

    av_register_all();
    avfilter_register_all();

    if ((ret = init_filters()) < 0)
        goto end;
    /*...*/
    system("Pause");
    return ret ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have removed the codes I think are unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code `-22` or `EINVAL` is returned in case of one or more invalid arguments. The `buffersrc` filter you're about to create takes an additional argument string (`args`) describing the dimensions and the format of the incoming video. You comment out the creation of the string which is why the error is produced.

```
// this should not be comment out, or replaced with way of setting the arguments
/*sprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
            dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
            dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);*/
 ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in", 
                                    args, NULL, filter_graph);
```

If the filter does not know how big the incoming frames are and how to interpret the read values (e.g. are there 3 RGB channels or 3 YUV channels? How are those laid out, i.e. are they planar or packed?) then how should it read them? Right, it can't and it tries to tell you that with the error message.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I commented it out because it incurred a compiler error in my c++ code, I have fixed it by removing the second parameter and now it works as expected.

Comment: A better fix is to keep the `sizeof args`, but call `snprintf()`, which appears to be what was intended.